# Passing "*" through command line arguments in C lists all files in directory

Tags: c, arguments, command, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to pass 3 strings from command line argument, the purpose is to pass a mathematical equation as strings that then get converted into `int` and math operator.

When I run `./program 1 + 1`, I get: `argv[0]: ./program , argv[1]: 1, argv[2]: +, argv[3]: 1` as expected.
But when I run `./program 1 * 1` instead `argv[2]` causes the following to occur:

`argv[1] = 1 argv[2] = file_01 argv[3] = file_02 argv[4] = file_03 argv[5] = file_04 argv[6] = file_05 argv[7] = file_06 argv[8] = 1`

the files are in the same folder as the executable of the program.

So Im having trouble passing `*` through command line.

`printf("Value stored in argv [2]:%c\n", *argv[2]);`

the result is
Value stored in `argv[2]:C`

Comment: Did you try putting `*` in quotes?  Or put the whole expression in quotes, and parse it in the program?

Comment: The `*` will be expanded to the filenames in the current directory. Put the * between quotes, like `./program 1 "*" 1`. Try typing `echo "*"` and then `echo *` on the command line.

Comment: for the purpose of the project I'm working on it needs to run as so `./program 1 * 1`.
It works fine with 1 + 1, 1 - 1, 4 / 2, those char strings are all passed properly but for some reason `*` does not.

Comment: None of those other characters are glob wildcards used in shell filename expansion, that's why.

Comment: If you're using zsh, you can use `noglob ./program 1 * 1` to suppress the expansion, but otherwise, yeah, you have to escape the *.

Comment: Sidenote: This is not related to C but a shell problem.

Comment: Often 'x' is used to indicate multiplication... `result = 5 x 7`.... Jus sayin'...